# Swift 3.0. Add views to UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need a custom `UISearchBar`. With the standard text field but with other views too (2 checkbox and a `UIDatePicker`). Has anyone an idea about customising the `UISearchBar`? I've read a lot of posts related to changing size and colours, but no one explains how to add more views to it.

UPDATE

Found a solution. See answer below

Comment: You can create your own custom filter with for that.

Comment: Put everything (UISearchBar included) in a container UIView.

Comment: According to your requirement you can't customize the default UISearchBar. But you can create your own custom searchbar.

Comment: Has anyone an idea on where I can find examples ? I need also to implement the sliding effect then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Not having found any solution I've spent a couple of days implementing myself the code. If anybody needs it, please write a comment down here.